# Why is $f(n) = g^n$ a homomorphism?

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

I found following statement:

> *Let G be a group (written multiplicatively) and let $g ∈ G$ be fixed.
> Then the function $f \colon\mathbb{Z}\to G$ defined by $f(n) = g^n$ is a homomorphism
> (laws of exponents).*

As far as I know a map is a homomorphism if $f(ab)=f(a)f(b) \forall a,b$ and the law of exponents tells me that $f(nm)=a^{nm}=(a^n)^m=f(a^n)$ rather than $f(n)f(m)$...

Comment: The operation on $Z$ is addition, not multiplication (the integers are not a group under multiplication). So you want $f(n+m) = f(n)f(m)$, which holds, since $f(n)f(m) = g^ng^m = g^{n+m} = f(n+m)$.

Comment: This is neither linear algebra nor elementary number theory. It's obviously group theory.

Comment: To be precise, a homomorphism between a group $(H,\cdot)$ and a group $(G,\odot)$ (where $\cdot$ and $\odot$ are the operations that give the group structures) is a map $f\colon H\to G$ such that $f(a\cdot b) = f(a)\odot f(b)$. Writing "$f(ab)=f(a)f(b)$" is usually harmless abuse of notation, but must be understood in context.

Answer (score 2):

When you are trying to show that a function is a homomorphism you need to consider what is the group operation. In this case the group operation on $\mathbb{Z}$ is regular addition, so the law of exponents tell you that: $$f(n)f(m) = g^ng^m = g^{n+m} = f(n+m)$$

So $f$ is indeed a homomorphism.